# VSCode disable highlight matching

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I replace this annoying white rectangle with anything nicer?

[image]

I tried to disable it in user settings using

```
"editor.matchBrackets": "never",
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: They're **not** brackets, did you try `occurrencesHighlight`? Or change the colour in the theme.

Comment: You're right .. it is the theme ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

That highlighting appears to be `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` assuming you selected `editor`.   There is also `editor.selectionHighlightBorder` you can change.  Like so:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": { 

  "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#e90505",
  "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#ff000080"  // digits 7 and 8 are opacity
}
```

You can turn off this highlighting of selection matches by disabling this setting:

> Editor: Selection Highlight

Such highlighting could also be the result of find matches.  Please advise if that is what you used, the Find/Replace widget.